# when extends ListActivity then not work onClickListener

Tags: android

when I insert data then that data display in custome list view and also put button in list view So, now When click button at that time perform some action there fore I need to create onClickListener for button, So  when extends ListActivity then not work onClickListener in my appication in android....
    I also send code for this....

```
public class MydatabaseforlistActivity extends ListActivity {
    DbHelper dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button btnEdit,btnDel;
    String[] id;
    String[] title;
    int size;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*{
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);*/
        //setContentView(R.layout.listcarda);
        dbhelper = new DbHelper(this);

        dbhelper.oninsert("HELLO");

        dbhelper.oninsert("hjkhkjhl");

        dbhelper.oninsert("happy mother");

        dbhelper.oninsert("happy sorry");

                  db=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { DbHelper.U_ID,
                 DbHelper.TITLE }, null, null, null, null, null);
                 int i = 0;
        c.moveToFirst();
        size = c.getCount();
        id = new String[size];
        title = new String[size];
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            id[i] = c.getString(1);
        //  title[i] = c.getString(2);
            i++;
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        //lv = getListView();
        setListAdapter(new Notes(this));
```

Comment: u didn't write the code for onclicklistener!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MydatabaseforlistActivity extends ListActivity 
            implements onClickListener {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);

              }
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
             // yourButton was clicked!
           }
       }   
  }
```